# how to list remote exported NFSv4 volumes?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

When I use NFSv3, I can use the **showmount** command to list the volumes:

> NAME
>          showmount - show mount information for an NFS server
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          /usr/sbin/showmount [ -adehv ] [ --all ] [ --directories ] [ --exports ] [ --help ] [ --version ] [ host ]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          showmount  queries  the  mount  daemon on a remote host for information about the state of the NFS server on that
>          machine.  With no options showmount lists the set of clients who are mounting from that host.   The  output  from
>          showmount is designed to appear as though it were processed through ''sort -u''.

However, it seems that NFSv4 volumes will NOT be listed.
How can I get a list of NFSv4 volumes exported from a remote host?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pure NFSv4 doesn't provide a way to get list of exports. Nevertheless, most of nfs servers do export with nfsv4 and nfsv3 at the same time. This makes possible to discover v4 exports. In general, NFSv4 builds a pseudo file system from the list of exports and exports a pseudo '/'.